# Why is boost::function slow?

Tags: c++, performance, boost

I was doing some timing tests and one of my tests was to compare different ways of calling functions. I called N functions using various means. I tried regular function calls, virtual function calls, function pointers, and boost::function.

I did this in Linux using gcc and -O3 optimization.

As expected virtual calls are slower than regular function calls. However the surprising thing is that boost::function clocked in at 33% slower than the virtual calls.

Has anyone else noticed this? Any clue to why this is?

Comment: Did you make sure you had multiple variants of the virtual function implemented? Compilers can be kind of tricky and deduce the type if they are sure only one class actually implements the virtual function..

Comment: I didn't think any of that was going because the difference was the regular function call and the virtual function call was large enough that I was satisfied that no tricky compiler optimizations were taking place.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're against a wall for performance, you may be interested in a less-slow alternative: 

[Fast Delegate][1]


  [1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular functions can be *inlined* by the compiler if possible, but `boost::function` can **never** be inlined. That is one big difference.

The second difference is, `boost::function` implements [type-erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) which means it uses *indirection* to invoke the actual function. Means it first calls a virtual function which then invokes your function. So typically it involves (minimum) two function calls (one of them is `virtual`). That is **huge** difference.

So based on this analysis, one could infer this (without even  writing test code):

```
slowest ------------------------------------------------------> fastest 
        boost::function < virtual function < regular function 
slowest ------------------------------------------------------> fastest
```

which is indeed the case, in your test code.

Note that it is true for `std::function` also (which is available since C++11).

Comment: And calling a `boost::function` is never just 1 function call.

Comment: does that apply to C++11 lambda as well ?

Comment: @GreyGeek no, because lambdas are not `std::function`.  In fact, they can easily be more efficient than a C style function pointer, as the function called is exposed in the type of the variable.

Comment: @GreyGeek: No. Lambdas don't use indirection. They can even be inlined. So they're pretty much fast, and likely to be faster than (regular) function pointer.

Comment: I'd assume that boost::function <= virtual function, since that really depends on what you put into the function. The type erasure mechanism really only has a single virtual function call that cannot be inlined, everything else potentially can be. If you use it with boost::bind, I guess quite a bit of overhead comes from that.

Answer (score 2):

A `boost::function` can hold not only a function pointer, but an entire copy of an arbitrary object which it calls a possibly virtual `operator()` on.

It can help to understand how it might work (for exposition).

Here is a toy implementation of a `boost::function` type trick:

```
struct helper_base { virtual void do_it() = 0; };
template<typename Func>
struct helper:helper_base {
  Func func;
  helper(Func f):func(f) {}
  virtual void do_it() override { func(); }
};
struct do_something_later {
  boost::unique_ptr<helper_base> pImpl;
  template<typename Func>
  do_something_later( Func f ):pImpl(make_shared<helper<Func>>(f))
  {}
  void operator()() { (*pImpl).do_it(); }
private:
  do_something_later( do_something_later const& ); // deleted
  void operator=( do_something_later const& ); // deleted
};
```

Here my `do_something_later` takes an arbitrary object (Func) and calls `operator()` on it on demand.  It wraps the type of the thing we are calling `operator()` on in a type erasure helper, and then invokes the `operator()` via a virtual function.

`Func` type could be a function pointer, or it could be a functor with state.  Anything copyable with an operator() is fair game.  As far as the user of `do_something_later` is concerned, there is only one binary interface.

`boost::function` (and `std::function`) uses basically this same technique (with lots of improvements) to turn a whole set of possible interfaces into one interface.  The cost involves calling a `virtual` function (or the equivalent level of indirection).

Comment: Good explanation. I'm still wondering why any virtual dispatch is necessary? Why not skip the helper and just include Func directly inside struct do_something_later?

Comment: Because then `do_something_later` would have to template on the type of `Func`.  Instead only the constructor has to.  The above code builds a custom `helper` for each `Func` type that knows how big the `Func` object is, and knows what the signature of `operator()` is (is it virtual?  What calling convention does it use?  Does it actually return `int`, and as such expects space for the return value on the stack?  Does it actually return `std::vector<int>` and as such we need to clean up the returned object in `do_it()`?)

Answer (score 0):

The real reason for the observed slowness is that the `boost::function` in addition to two indirections compares the pointer to zero. If this test was omitted, then the call would perform as fast as a virtual function (which also involves two indirections -- one pointer to the vtable and another to the actual function).